# Why won't my S_ISDIR and S_ISREG return the correct directory/file name?

Tags: c

Why won't my S_ISDIR and S_ISREG return the correct directory/file name?

When I run my program using a test directory that I made with 3 other directories and a text file inside, only the printf() for Dir executes.

```
#include "dirAssignment.h"

//Struct
typedef struct directories{

}directories;


//Method to look for directories and files:
void search(const char *fileName){
    struct stat dirInfo;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    DIR *dp;

    //Checks to see if there is an error with the fileName:
    if (lstat(fileName, &dirInfo) < 0)
        {
        //Error:
        printf("Something went wrong!\n");
        printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
    }

    //Checks to see if file can be opened:
    if ((dp = opendir(fileName)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", fileName);
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    //If file can be opened, get all the files from the directory:
    while((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {   
        //Check for( and Ignore) parent and self:
        if (strcmp(dirp->d_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(dirp->d_name,"..") == 0)        
        {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s:\t",dirp->d_name);


        if(S_ISDIR(dirInfo.st_mode))
        {
            printf("Dir\n");
        }
        else if(S_ISREG(dirInfo.st_mode))
        {
            printf("File\n");
        }
    /*
        else if(S_ISDIR(dirp->d_name, &dirInfo))
        {
            //stat(fileName, &dirInfo);

            //Checks to see if the file is a directory:
            if (S_ISDIR(getcwd(dirp->d_name,512).st_mode))
            {
                printf("directory in: %s\n", fileName);
            }
            //Must be a file:
            else if (S_ISREG(getcwd(dirp->d_name,512).st_mode))
            {
                printf("file in: %s\n", fileName);
            }
            //No clue how you got here!
            else
            {
                printf("Danger Will Robinson, Danger... Danger!!!\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Danger Will Robinson, Danger... Danger!!!\n");
        }
    */

     }//End of while loop
}//End of Search method

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //Variables go here:
    int i = 0;
    char const *fileName = argv[1];


    //Prompt the user:
    printf("Enter starting fileName: %s\n",argv[1]);
    //Starting file:
    printf("Starting from file: %s\n...\n\n\n\n", fileName);

    //Lettuce(lol) find some files and directories!
    search(fileName);


    return 0;
}//End of main method
```

Comment: `#include "dirAssignment.h"` Sorry, homework dumps need to be a *bit* more disguised than that. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to write a [**Minimal, Complete**, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: I wasn't trying to hide the fact that it is a homework assignment. Just trying to give whoever may have an answer all the code I have because maybe I've written something wrong leading up to my question. The only question I had is why am I getting the print out that I'm getting when I hit my if statements. I didn't think I was asking anyone to finish a project for me. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: for use to have a clear view of the source of your runtime problem, we expect code that cleanly compiles.  The posted code contains a 'home grown' header file: `dirAssignment.h`  But the contents of that file are missing.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure that command line parameter actually was entered by the user.  If the desired command line parameter is not entered, then should execute something like: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <inputFileName>\n", argv[0] );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in `stdlib.h` and `printf()` and `fprintf()` are found in `stdio.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that you use the wrong variable. `dirInfo` is init by this line `if (lstat(fileName, &dirInfo) < 0)`. that's why always print Dir.

```
   if(S_ISDIR(dirInfo.st_mode))
    {
        printf("Dir\n");
    }
    else if(S_ISREG(dirInfo.st_mode))
    {
        printf("File\n");
    }
```

on linux, maybe you can use `dirp->d_type` to get type. read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html)

if want to use S_ISREG/S_ISDIR, just call `lstat` to get file status first.